# Create an if-else condition column in dask dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dask

I need to create a column which is based on some condition on dask dataframe. In pandas it is fairly straightforward:

```
ddf['TEST_VAR'] = ['THIS' if x == 200607 else  
              'NOT THIS' if x == 200608 else 
              'THAT' if x == 200609 else 'NONE'  
              for x in ddf['shop_week'] ]
```

While in dask I have to do same thing like below:

```
def f(x):
    if x == 200607:
         y= 'THIS'
    elif x == 200608 :
         y= 'THAT'
    else :
         y= 1 
    return y

ddf1 = ddf.assign(col1 = list(ddf.shop_week.apply(f).compute()))
ddf1.compute()
```

Questions:

1. Is there a better/more straightforward way to achieve it?
2. I can't modify the first dataframe ddf, i need to create ddf1 to se the changes is dask dataframe Immutable object?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Answers:

1. What you're doing now is almost ok.  You don't need to call `compute` until you're ready for your final answer.

   ```
   # ddf1 = ddf.assign(col1 = list(ddf.shop_week.apply(f).compute()))
   ddf1 = ddf.assign(col1 = ddf.shop_week.apply(f))
   ```

   For some cases `dd.Series.where` might be a good fit

   ```
   ddf1 = ddf.assign(col1 = ddf.shop_week.where(cond=ddf.balance > 0, other=0))
   ```
2. As of version 0.10.2 you can now insert columns directly into dask.dataframes

   ```
   ddf['col'] = ddf.shop_week.apply(f)
   ```

Comment: The dask dataframes are mutable by default or they are mutable post release of version 0.10.2?

Comment: In the most recent version of Dask, version 0.10.2, dask.dataframes support column assignment

Comment: Thanks for the answer @MRocklin

Answer (score 1):

You could just use:

```
f = lambda x: 'THIS' if x == 200607 else 'NOT THIS' if x == 200608 else 'THAT' if x == 200609 else 'NONE'
```

And then:

```
ddf1 = ddf.assign(col1 = list(ddf.shop_week.apply(f).compute()))
```

Unfortunately I don't have an answer to the second question or I don't understand it...

Answer (score 0):

A better approach might be pull out the column as a dask array and then perform some nested `where` operations before adding it back to the dataframe:

```
import dask.array as da

x = ddf['shop_week'].to_dask_array()

df['TEST_VAR'] = \
    da.where(x == 200607, 'THIS',
    da.where(x == 200608, 'NOT THIS',
    da.where(x == 200609, 'THAT', 'NONE')))

df['TEST_VAR'].compute()
```