# Create a new column after if-else in dask

Tags: pandas, numpy, if-statement, dask-dataframe

`df[‘new_col’] = np.where(df[‘col1’] == df[‘col2’] , True, False)`, where col1 and col2 are both str data types, seems pretty straight forward. What is the more efficient method to create a column in dask after an if else statement? I tried the recommendation from this [Create an if-else condition column in dask dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38608446/create-an-if-else-condition-column-in-dask-dataframe) but it is taking forever. It has only processed about 30% after about an hour. I have 13mil rows and 70 columns

Answer (score 1):

IIUC use if need set column to boolean:

```
df['new_col'] = df['col1'] == df['col2']
```

If need set to another values:

```
df['new_col'] = 'val for true'
ddf = df.assign(col1 = df.new_col.where(cond=df['col1'] == df['col2'], other='val for false'))
```

Comment: What does IIUC mean?

Comment: @buddingpro - it means If I  Understant It

Comment: Thanks, new vocabulary! What I am trying to do is create a new ddf with columns from those Boolean values from source ddf. `var1=ddf[col1]==ddf[col2], var2=ddf[col3]==ddf[col4],...` up to var8, then create a new dask df from those var1 to var8

Comment: My question is how to make it faster because calling pd.DataFrame is taking a long while

Comment: if I want True and False as the values, using your lines: is this the right one?: ` ddf['match1'] = True;
ddf = ddf.assign('col1' = ddf.match1.where(cond=ddf['col1'] == ddf['col2'], other=False))` @jezrael